# ConcurrentModificationException with WeakHashMap

Tags: multithreading, weakhashmap

I have the code below but I'm getting ConcurrentModificationException, how should I avoid this issue? (I have to use WeakHashMap for some reason)

```
WeakHashMap<String, Object> data = new WeakHashMap<String, Object>();

 // some initialization code for data

  for (String key : data.keySet()) {
        if (data.get(key) != null && data.get(key).equals(value)) {
            //do something to modify the key
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Probably because your `// do something` in the iteration is actually modifying the underlying collection.

From [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

And from [(Weak)HashMap's keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html#keySet%28%29):

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined.

Comment: yes, you are right! I have to update the key while iterating the keyset, so is there a workaround to this issue if I still have to use WeakHashMap? Thanks.

Comment: can I clone the data.keyset() and iterate this cloned set instead while modifying the key of the original data?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Javadoc for WeakHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) class explains why this would happen:

> Map invariants do not hold for this class. Because the garbage
>   collector may discard keys at any time, a WeakHashMap may behave as
>   though an unknown thread is silently removing entries

Furthermore, the iterator generated under the hood by the enhanced for-loop you're using is of fail-fast type as per quoted explanation in that javadoc.

> The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections
>   returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are
>   fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the
>   iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own
>   remove method, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

Therefore your loop can throw this exception for these reasons:

1. Garbage collector has removed an object in the keyset.
2. Something outside the code added an object to that map.
3. A modification occurred inside the loop.

As your intent appears to be processing the objects that are not GC'd yet, I would suggest using an iterator as follows:

```
Iterator<String> it = data.keySet().iterator();
int count = 0;
int maxTries = 3;
while(true) {
    try {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String str = it.next();
            // do something
        }
        break;
    } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
        it = data.keySet().iterator(); // get a new iterator
        if (++count == maxTries) throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the key set first, but note that you hold the strong reference after that:

```java
Set<KeyType> keys;
while(true) {
   try {
       keys = new HashSet<>(weakHashMap.keySet());
       break;
   } catch (ConcurrentModificationException ignore) {
   }
}

for (KeyType key : keys) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

WeakHashMap's entries are automatically removed when no ordinary use of the key is realized anymore, this may happens in a different thread. While cloning the `keySet()` into a different `Set` a concurrent Thread may remove entries meanwhile, in this case a `ConcurrentModificationException` will 100% be thrown! You must synchronize the cloning.

Example:

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(data);
```

Please understand that

```
Collections.synchronizedSet(data.keySet());
```

Can **not** be used because `data.keySet()` rely on data's instance who is not synchronized here! More detail: synchronize(keySet) prevents the execution of methods on the keySet but keySet's remove-method is never called but WeakHashMap's remove-method is called so you have to synchronize over WeakHashMap!